# Looking for open platform software framework for remote testing

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework

I am currently looking for a software framework for my project involving GPU boards and graphics tests.

My project is to find a software framework to use where I can remotely run graphics tests on my GPU and have it automated. Basically what I have is 5 separate graphics tests (they are Linux scripts in my directory that I just execute via command line) that I run my machine which the GPU board is connected through the USB port.

I SSH in using Putty and connect through the serial port (which is to connect to the GPU board) to run each test by hand for 10 minutes each. It returns the frames per second to me on the command line when I kill the test. What I am looking for is a way to automate this.

I need to remotely run these 5 separate tests from another machine and be able to run all 5 tests back-to-back for a certain period of time without having to manually run each one. Meaning I need to start the scripts and have it go and return the frames per second for each tests without any more interaction from me.

I was wondering if any of you experts may have some software you have used in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I've successfully configured similar test automation framework for hardware boards (BeagleBone and others) using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org).***

> Jenkins can run shell scripts remotely (using ssh). Jenkins agents can represent boards under test. You can handle agent names in scripts in order to access certain board (agent names will be accessible via env variables out-of-box). Also test runs can be easily scheduled with Jenkins.
>   Jenkins is absolutely free to use.

---

You can try others distributed CI solutions as well ([TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo), [Continuum](http://continuum.apache.org/), etc.). I just tell that I had positive experience with Jenkins.

---

**Also there is automated testing system called [LAVA (Linaro Automated Validation Architecture)](http://www.linaro.org/projects/test-validation/).**
You can find general information on it [here](http://www.linaro.org/blog/community-blog/automated-validation-with-lava/).

Comment: Wow exactly what I am looking for with the LAVA system. Thank you

Comment: Everything has pros and cons. :) As for me LAVA is not so convenient about creating testcases. P.S. Please vote for / accept answers that were useful for you.